What are some issues with using robust standard errors when you do not need to?
I've been reading the web about this. Some text books mention one line in passing that it can violate some assumptions but never really say which ones.
When googling I seem to get into a rabbit hole related to a debate whether or not to always use HC SE. Which every just says yes.
What are some issues of using HC1 or white standard errors when they are not needed?

My guess is: (1) The difference tends to be small under mild heteroscedasticity. (2) An implementation might not be readily available for every model. (3) It's more steps.

The HC standard errors are noisier, so if you have relatively small sample size and the model is close to being correctly specified you'll get worse confidence interval coverage and worse control of size of tests with the HC standard errors.
